# Recode (car) not working to convert NA's to 0 and values to 1

Tags: r

An R beginner here,(doing my best to ask the question right).

I ran this code previously on my ds to recode all NA's of a variable into '0' and all values into' 1'.

```
MyVars$Var5 <- car::recode(MyVars$Var4, "NA =  '0'; else = '1'")
```

Now I get an error message I did not previously get:

> Error: Can't convert  to .

I've tried to do the same with `ifesle`. Also not working.
The right packages are installed.

What am I doing wrong? Help appreciated.

Comment: Could you add reproducible data? A sample of `MyVars$Var4` it should be enough

Comment: @iago Thank you, the problem is solved! Will add data next time. Learning new things with every question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with base R using `is.na` :

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1, 2, 3, NA, 5, NA))
df$b <- as.integer(!is.na(df$a))
df
#   a b
#1  1 1
#2  2 1
#3  3 1
#4 NA 0
#5  5 1
#6 NA 0
```

This will assign 0 to all `NA` values and 1 for all other values. I have created a new column `b` here for comparison purposes but you can overwrite the same column (`a`) if needed.